# Proving convexity of the set$ \{ (x,y): 25y^2 - x^2 \geq 9 \} $

Tags: convex-analysis

I need to show that the following set is convex:

$$\{(x,y): \{||(x,3)|| \leq 5y, \:  y \leq 1\} $$

So I rewrote the first constraint to $ 25y^2 - x^2 \geq 9$ and the minimum of this constraint is at $(x,y) = (0, 0.6)$

So I came up with the following:

Suppose we have $x = \langle x_1, x_2 \rangle , \: y=\langle y_1, y_2 \rangle  \in S \text{ for } 0 \leq t \leq 1$

Then we get the following:

$$(1-t)x + ty = \langle (1-t)x_1 + ty_1, (1-t)x_2+ty_2 \rangle =\\
25\left[(1-t)x_2+ty_2 \right]\left[(1-t)x_2+ty_2 \right] - [(1-t)x_1 + ty_1)((1-t)x_1+ty_1)=\\
25[(1-t)^2x_2^2 + 2(1-t)tx_2y_2 + t^2y_2^2] - \;... \\ 
[(1-t)^2x_1^2 + 2(1-t)tx_1y_1 + t^2y_1^2] = \\
(1-t)^2 (25x_2^2 - x_1^2) + t^2 (25x_2^2 - x_1^2) \;+ \;...
$$

I am a bit confused by the exponentials and as a result, the multiplications, e.g. $2(1-t)tx_2y_2$ . Am I doing this correctly or am I making a mistake?

I was also thinking about creating a composite function but I am not quite sure.

Comment: This set is not convex (note $(x, y) \in S$ implies $(-x, -y)\in S$, so $(0,0) \in S$ if $S$ is convex)

Comment: but this is not an equation rather an inequality

Comment: While your reformulation is nonconvex, the original set you wrote *is* indeed convex. What tools can you use from your class to prove convexity? Do you need to prove it directly, or can you use the fact that a lower-level set of a convex function is convex?